# Exit while loop of mouseDown event

Tags: c#, while-loop, mousedown

I am trying to make my Form, which has no border, moveable with holding the left mousebutton down and exit the while loop, when releasing the mousebutton.
But the code I have right now doesn't exit the loop on release.

```
    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseDown = true;

        while (mouseDown)
        {
            mouseX = MousePosition.X;
            mouseY = MousePosition.Y - 30;
            this.SetDesktopLocation(mouseX, mouseY);

            if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left)
                mouseDown = false;
        }
```

I also tried to add a mouseUp event but it cant happen as long as mouseDown is active.

```
    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseDown = true;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712309/c-sharp-loop-while-mousedown-button-pressed

Comment: The function parameter MouseEventArgs e does not change value during execution

Comment: I am not a fan of adding mouse listeners via C#.  Usually I try to seperate a lot of the FrontEnd from C#

Comment: @FallenReaper implementing WPF application UI with C# is actually not that bad :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I fixed it for myself.

I just did this:

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDown = true;
}

private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDown = false;
}

private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (mouseDown)
    {
        mouseX = MousePosition.X - 20;
        mouseY = MousePosition.Y - 40;
        this.SetDesktopLocation(mouseX, mouseY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using a loop in the on mouse up event you are locking the thread. You could use the MouseMove event with a public variable to check if the mouse is down.