# Move mouse while holding a Key

Tags: c#

I've been trying to setup a windows application form with a simple function, I want to make my mouse pointer move down(from any position) as long as I have my "F" key holding. The moment I release "F", pointer should stop moving. So far I've managed to make my mouse pointer get in a position after pressing "F" but can't make my mouse to keep moving while holding the key.

Comment: Can you share some code to show what you've tried?  And what problems you've faced?

Comment: Show us your method for this keypress and what you are trying to achieve. There are many ways to solve this but if its just a playful application i would just implement a timer and a checkflag: on keydown set a bool and start the timer to repeat your method and on keyup stop: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127270/c-sharp-how-to-loop-while-mouse-button-is-held-down) is Doggett's answer which you can adapt to keypresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use **Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key)** method, so you can increase the position of mouse in the direction you want while the key is still down.

For MSDN Reference :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.iskeydown(v=vs.110).aspx

I hope it helps you, good luck !