# I am using WinForms C#, I want to make an event where my command is executed upon holding the mouse, instead of repeating the clicks

Tags: c#, winforms

I know that there is a mouse click on a button, however I want my program to react to the button being held pressed with a given interval. I don't want the user to repeatedly be pressing on the button, instead he should just hold it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# how to loop while mouse button is held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127270/c-sharp-how-to-loop-while-mouse-button-is-held-down)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try to achieve it via [MouseDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown?view=netcore-3.1), [MouseUp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mouseup?view=netcore-3.1) and [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=netcore-3.1).

First, create a new timer instance as followed.

```
    private System.Timers.Timer myTimer;
    int count = 0;

    private void myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        count++;
        if(count == 3)
        {
            // this triggered when hold the button 3 seconds
            Console.WriteLine("execute command");
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000); // interval: 1s
        this.myTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(myTimer_Elapsed);
        this.myTimer.AutoReset = true;
    }
```

Then, start the timer when mouse down and stop when mouse up.

```
private void button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // start the timer
    myTimer.Enabled = true;
    myTimer.Start();
}

private void button_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // stop the timer
    myTimer.Stop();
    myTimer.Enabled = false;
    // reset counter
    count = 0;
}
```